# Does Tkinter have a refresh method?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am using Tkinter.

```
import Tkinter as tk

class App(tk.Frame):
  def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
     ....
root = tk.Tk()
root.title("title")

app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Does it has a refresh? Because I want to refresh my frame.
Is `root.refresh()` is possible?

Answer (score 31):

There is a [Tk.update()](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter.Misc-class.html#update) and a [Tk.update_idletasks()](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter.Misc-class.html#update_idletasks). Both will force the UI to be refreshed, but depending on what you're actually trying to do it might not be what you're looking for.

Comment: thanks junuxx for the reply, but I think it is not what I am looking for... I am trying do some changes on Tkinter UI... I have post the question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19462431/python-tkinter-label-changing-text-value-by-button-command#19462431 I hope you have some idea, thanks

Answer (score 5):

It's very simple :) Create a function to refresh as given below and call it using a widget.

```
def refresh(self):
    self.destroy()
    self.__init__()
```

It worked for me. All you have to do is destroy your main frame `tk.Frame`and call the constructor again `self.__init__()`.

Comment: I wonder what would be the overhead for doing this